# How do I make the file description field required?

Tags: entities, files

In Drupal 7, I need users to enter a file description, how do I make this field required?
Also on another note, I would love to make this field a select list, there's no clear way to do this aside writing a custom module. Any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean by making it a select field instead? Do you want to have some sort of predefined values and let the users choose one?

Answer (score 1):

Code snippet for making a file's description field required:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_field_widget_form_alter().
 */
function MYMODULE_field_widget_form_alter(&$element, &$form_state, $context) {
  if ($context['field']['field_name'] == 'field_MYFIELD' && $context['instance']['widget']['type'] == 'file_generic') {
    $element_children = element_children($element, TRUE);
    foreach($element_children as $key) {
      $element[$key]['#process'][] = 'MYMODULE_file_field_description_required';
    }
  }
}

/**
 * Require description to be set.
 */
function MYMODULE_file_field_description_required($element, &$form_state, $form) {
  $element['description']['#required'] = TRUE;
  return $element;
}
```